# css alignment Issue in react js

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

```
<div> 
  <div className='dif'> 
      <div style={{marginLeft:10, bottom: '0', left: '0',color:'#45b37c',position:'relative'}} className = 'fl big-font'>$108</div>
      <div style={{ margin:'20px', textAlign:'right', position: 'absolute', bottom: '0', right: '0',}}> Target: $1234</div>
      <div style={{ marginRight:'20px', marginTop:'10px', textAlign:'right', position: 'absolute', bottom: '0', right: '0',}}> Actual: $1234</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This the code I am using.

[image]

If you see the image. I am trying to set both $20 and target and actual divs to left an right bottom of the main div.
But when I increase the size of the left text. I goes upwards.
Can any body tell me how to fix it to the bottom.
I  tried text-align but no success.

```html
<div>
  <div class='dif'>
    <div style="margin-left:10; bottom: 0; left: 0; color:#45b37c; position:relative;" class="fl big-font">$108</div>
    <div style="margin: 20px; text-align: right; position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0 "> Target: $1234</div>
    <div style="margin-right: 20px; margin-top: 10px; text-align: right; position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;"> Acutal: $1234</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have `position:'realtive'` where it should be `position:'relative'`. Does that help?

Comment: Absolute positioning is rarely necessary (or simple). I'd look at using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). I'd also get those great gobs of style out of my markup and into a proper stylesheet (or at least an embedded style tag).

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox in order to make the two items at the bottom:

```
.dif {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end; 
}
```

And wrap the last 2 elements into div, you should also remove the top div, I think isn't necessary:

```
<div className='dif'> 
    <div style={{marginLeft:10, color:'#45b37c'}} className='fl big-font'>$108</div>
    <div>
      <div style={{ margin:'20px', textAlign:'right', position: 'absolute', bottom: '0', right: '0',}}> Target: $1234</div>
      <div style={{ marginRight:'20px', marginTop:'10px', textAlign:'right', position: 'absolute', bottom: '0', right: '0',}}> Acutal: $1234</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: same issue. If I keep both left and right text font size same then they are on same line but If I change the left text font size and increase it. Then it moves upward and right side text remains at bottom. As shown in image